# Summarising results of multiple Pandas Boolean columns

Tags: python, pandas, count, boolean

I have a Pandas dataset with multiple Boolean columns (effectively flagging what type of sustainability targets a company has set). I would like to summarise the results of these these columns by counting the number of True and False occurances.

A simplified example of the dataset:

```
data1 = [['Apple', True, True, True], ['Tesla', True, False, True], ['Nike', True, False, False]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Company', 'Carbon-target', 'Water-target', 'Waste-target'])

  Company  Carbon-target  Water-target  Waste-target
0   Apple           True          True          True
1   Tesla           True         False          True
2    Nike           True         False         False
```

Desired output:

```
                True         False
Carbon-target   3            0 
Water-target    1            2
Waste-target    2            1
```

Currently, the only operator I can think of is the word_count function, but would require several iterations. Is there a simpler way?

Thank you !

Comment: Something like: `df1.filter(regex=r'-target$').apply(pd.value_counts).T` ? Or maybe: `df1.filter(regex=r'-target$').melt().groupby(['variable', 'value']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)` ?

Comment: One modification `df1.filter(regex=r'-target$').apply(pd.value_counts).T.fillna(0)` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select boolean columns

```
x = df.select_dtypes(bool)
```

Count `True` and `False` values

```
out = pd.DataFrame({True: x.sum(), False: df.shape[0] - x.sum()})
```

Output

```
               True  False
Carbon-target     3      0
Water-target      1      2
Waste-target      2      1
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you Vishnudev !